# Shell: Wait that a file has been copied

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I've a shell script which list files of a folder and then do an action on them(print into a PDF), but very often I get a blank PDF. If I remove the generated PDF, the new PDF is always correctly generated.

I've the impression that is because my script started to print BEFORE the file has been fully copied(the copy is made through the OS explorer, with a save as, or just copy-paste).

It's absolutely not me which manage when someone add a new file, the copy comes from users which uses a network share.

so is there a way to have something like this?

```
for inputFile in `ls -l $SearchPattern | grep ^- | awk '{print $9}'`
do
   //CHECK_THAT_THE_FILE_HAS_ALREADY_BEEN_FULLY_SAVED_ONCE 
   //DO_MY_PRINT_HERE
done
```

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: What's wrong with `for inputFile in $SearchPattern; do ...` ?

Comment: can you set up a crontab to run every hour (or ?) and only process files with timestamps more than 5 (or ?) mins old? Good luck.

Comment: @glennjackman Regular expressions are not glob characters. Most regexps are impossible to write as glob patterns. `grep '^-'` in `ls -l` output says "give me all plain files".

Comment: @Jens, I would dispute "Most regexps are impossible to write as glob patterns", really complicated ones yes, but the regex `^-` is the glob `-*`. Anyway, `for inputFile in $SearchPattern; do [[ ! -f "$inputFile" ]] && continue; ...`

Comment: @glennjackman No, it's not. `-*` globs all files starting with a dash. How do you glob all plain files, which is what `ls -l | grep '^-'`does? (Have you ignored the -l option?) What is the glob equivalent for the regex '+' for "one or more of the preceding? How do you glob '?' for "zero or one of the preceding"?

Comment: @Jens, yes it is ;) -- the regex **pattern** `^-` is the same as the glob **pattern** `-*`. See my previous comment to see how to find plain files properly. I understand that it's not a simple regex and it's more verbose, but you really must not parse ls like the OP does. For files with spaces, piping `ls|grep|awk '{print $9}'` will not give you the actual filename. For more advanced regex quantifiers, you have to go beyond globs and use [bash patterns](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) which I believe ksh and zsh can also do.

Comment: @Jens: Shell glob patterns were chosen so they are suitable to customary file naming schemes. So long as you don't place arbitrary data in your filenames, shell glob patterns will easily be powerful enough (and less error prone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended by using

```
for inputFile in `find $SearchPattern2 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +1 -iname "*.pdf"`
```

the -cmin +1 indicate to find, that is has to list only file with the modification time >1min ago.

It's not 100% safe, but it will handle all my case with a lot of margin.

I didn't find how to do this in seconds

Answer (score 3):

If you are running under Linux and the filesystem is *local* to your server, then you can use the [inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) subsystem to wait until the file is closed and then trigger an action.  The [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki/) package includes the [inotifywait](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) program, which exposes inotify functionality to shell scripts.

For example, you can watch for the `close_write` event in a directory like this:

```
inotifywait -e close_write -m /path/to/directory
```

With this command running, doing this:

```
echo hello > /path/to/directory/file
```

Will generate output like this:

```
/path/to/directory/ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE hello
```

So there you have the directory and filename that generated the event.  In a shell script you can pipe this into a loop:

```
inotifywait -e close_write -m /path/to/directory | while read dir flags file; do
  ...do something with the file...
done
```

Comment: I don't have inotify helper on this server

Answer (score 2):

As someone pointed out, using the file modification time might be useful. I've quickly done this script that might be useful. It will wait until 5 seconds have passed since the last modification time of a given file:

```
#!/bin/bash

function getTimeFromLastChange() {
    file=${1}
    let lastAccess=$(stat --format=%Y ${file})
    let now=$(date +%s)
    let timePassed=$((now - lastAccess))
    echo ${timePassed}
}

file=./test
while [ true ]; do
    let lastChange=$(getTimeFromLastChange ${file})
    if [ "${lastChange}" -lt 5 ]; then
        echo "waiting"
        sleep 1
    else
        echo "done"
        exit
    fi
done

echo ${timePassed}
```

The key here is the "getTimeFromLastChange" function that uses stat (http://linux.die.net/man/1/stat) to get the last modification time for the given file in seconds since the unix epoch time. Then, it will get the current time using date (http://linux.die.net/man/1/date) (again, in seconds since the unix epoch time), substract them, and figure the total amount of seconds since the last modification time.

The main loop will wait until some "safe" amount of seconds have passed by. So you can try tunning this parameter and print the files that were written/modified some N amonut of seconds ago.

A sample run:

```
marcelog@host ~ $ touch ./test
marcelog@host ~ $ ./try.sh
waiting
waiting
waiting
done
```

It's not 100% safe. But I think it's worth giving it a try.

Hope it helps!

Comment: When is the modification time? At the start or the end of the copy?

Comment: When copying large files, you should notice that the modification time is updated as the data is written to disk. So it is actually updated  through the whole copying process. I've just tried the script I posted by copying a large file (over 600M) and it will wait as expected until 5 seconds have passed since the last modification time (which should be the last data copied/added to the file, effectively the end of the copying process)

Answer (score 0):

you should check the modification time of the data and have a threshold on that.
There is no other (easy) way to see if there is no more operation pending on the file.

so you should use

ls -l -t

in you find statement above and pipe that through a "sort" accordingly to you time threshhold.

Greetings